# Is is true that if $O(g) \subset O(h)$ and $ O(h)\subset O(f)$ then $ O(g)\subset O(f)$?

Tags: functions

Is is true that if $O(g) \subset O(h)$ and $ O(h)\subset O(f)$ then $ O(g)\subset O(f)$?

Also, I want to make sure I am correct when I say:

$f(n)$ is not a subset of $O(f)$

Then, what is the relationship between the function and the $O$ of the function?

Comment: For any sets $A\subset B \land B \subset C \Rightarrow A\subset C$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly you are asking about transitivity of big-$O$:
$$f\in O(g) \land g \in O(h) \Rightarrow f \in O(h)$$

"$f(n)$ is not subset of $O(f(n))$ " is true and holds $f\in O(f)$.

Comment: First, I want to thank you for your answer. Second, can you please clarify some points:

- what is the hat sign?

- $f$ is not a set so obviously, it is not a subset (unless I am missing something). I made a mistake and wanted to use $\in$ instead of a subset.  Also, I don't understand why you said $f \in O(f)$ if $\lim_{n\to \infty}{\frac{f}{f}}=1$?

Comment: Conception of subset used symbol "$\subset$" and is defined by following
$$(A \subset B) \Leftrightarrow (x\in A \Rightarrow x \in B)$$
Symbol "$\in$" is called belong and designate relation between set and element of this set. And last: $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(n)}{f(n)}=1$ holds for every $f\ne 0$ and have nothing in common with $f \in O(f)$, which holds for any $f$. May be you would like ask if $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}=1$ implies $f \in O(g)$?

Comment: In your definition above, is it for any $x$?

Comment: We know that if 
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}} =\infty \Rightarrow g(n) \in O(f)$$

Now if $g(n) =f(n) \Rightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}} =1$

Does that mean that $f(n) \in  O(f)$?

Is that more clear?

Comment: If in first comment you speak about subset definition, then yes, it's for all $x$. Next, As I wrote, always $f \in O(f)$ and this fact is not dependent on any other properties of $f$. Next, $\frac{f}{g}\to \infty$ implies $g\in O(f)$ and also $\frac{f}{g}\to 1$ implies $g\in O(f)$. What is not clear is that why you mix $f \in O(f)$  with $f$ and some $g$ relationship?

Comment: I see thanks. Can I post another question and tag you in the comments, if I think you can help?

Comment: If I can and your question will be inside my knowledge, then of course and with pleasure.